# Excel checkbox - edit text option not showing when right clicked

Tags: microsoft-excel, forms

This checkbox lets me edit the text from the right-click options:

[image]

This one doesn't:

[image]

Any advice why not, or how to fix it?
Note that the second is a copy of the first, which in turn was a copy of the one above it, and that I was able to edit it once, but not any more.

Comment: Do not choose to right-click and try editing it in the tool bar above.

Comment: Which option? In which tool bar - Developer?

Comment: Note: even the original text box that was working above is not now, but I realize I can double click into the text to edit it. Strangely inconsistent behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

I think  you selected 2 kinds of checkboxes. The one you are able to edit is a Form control while the checkbox you are unable to edit by right-clicking is an ActiveX control. Make sure that you select checkbox from Form Controls.

Comment: But the ActiveX checkbox has a different appearance and a different context menu.

Comment: I made the second, as noted, as a copy of the first - so how would it be a different control type?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way this can normally happen.

Therefore your Excel workbook has become corrupted.

Excel detects some types of corruption itself, when it will automatically start the File Recovery mode. In other cases, you must start the recovery process manually

Microsoft provide these instructions to manually [repair a corrupted workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53).